# Pandas Data Frame get the values only not the definition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign a variable into a pandas data frame but when I am printing it's giving me an output like this. its with index and definition.

```
    2    ['segment', 'deviceCategory', 'userType']
Name: Dimensions, dtype: object
```

is there a way to only get output like this in type list.

```
['segment', 'deviceCategory', 'userType']
```

I am just reading and storing into variables.

```
my_dim = df['Dimensions']
print(my_dim)
2    ['segment', 'deviceCategory', 'userType']
    Name: Dimensions, dtype: object
```

Expected Output:

```
['segment', 'deviceCategory', 'userType']
```

there must be a way to do that but not able to find.

Comment: `my_dim = df['Dimensions'].iat[0]`

Comment: whats that iat?

Comment: do I need to import something?

Comment: it is function for seelct first value of series

Comment: it works but the type is str. how can I convert into the list?

Comment: then use `import ast` and `my_dim = ast.literal_eval(my_dim)`